# EntireRow.Insert with formula from the above cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this Excel Worksheet
[image]

In **G6** there is a formula `=CONCATENATE(C6;D6;E6;F6;)`

I insert a new row with VBA

```
Range("C6").EntireRow.Insert
```

I would like to find in the new inserted row the formula I have above `=CONCATENATE()`

I tried `Range("C6").EntireRow.Insert xlDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove`.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand your story... Do you mean that there are formulas on row 6, pointing to row 4 and after insertion, the formula looses its reference? If not, please explain in detail what it is happening. Would you like to find a formula on the inserted row?

Comment: I will edit the question, sorry, hope you find it more clear now @FaneDuru

Comment: VBA doesn't do wonders! When you manually insert a row, does it keep any formula on it? You must copy your necessary formulas if this is what you need...

Comment: Would you like to have the formula updated for the new row, or pointing to the same range as the initial one? I posted an answer based on the first supposition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Range("G6").EntireRow.Insert xlDown
 Range("G6:G7").FillUp
```